# Multiple Classes in HTML Work in Chrome but not in Edge and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

This is by far one of the weirdest things I've seen. I decided to check back on a site I made a while ago, and of course something was off. I now mainly use Firefox and noticed the formatting looked odd. I switched to Chrome and everything looked great. I switched to Edge and everything was wrong again. I inspected element in all three and only in chrome did it show the CSS for each included class in the elements (login button, text entry boxes). In Edge and Firefox, only the CSS for the last class seemed to be included.

The site is https://avonctnhs.org

Does anyone have *any idea* what is going on here? The classes are set in HTML, there is no JavaScript adding the classes at runtime, etc; just HTML loaded from a file on a server.

Thank you so very much.

Edit: I spent a while searching and the only answers I could find where for people trying to add classes in JavaScript or people with typos that didn't work in any browser.

Additionally, all the code that should be needed should be visible with a nice quick inspect element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS files fail to load because your page relies on [HTML imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports) which is not supported by all the browsers.

Your source code has the following lines which should be replaced.

```
<!-- Additional Headers -->

<link rel="import" href="/core/custom-elements/text-input/text-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="/core/custom-elements/button/button.html">
```

The above lines can be replaced with the below code which is actually the contents of the above two files.

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

This should fix your issue. Here is an excerpt from MDN which states Firefox doesn't yet support HTML imports.

> Firefox will not ship HTML Imports in its current form. See this status update for more information. Until there is a consensus on the standard or alternative mechanisms are worked out, you can use a polyfill such as Google's webcomponents.js.